# Which method will be called when change display size?

Tags: android

According to [Google document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#screen-zoom),
I go to setting and change my device display zoom level, then turn back to my app. But the activity's onCreate method suddenly called, so that all properties are reset.

Please tell me how to handle this case. Save instance state?

Comment: 1) implement the activity life cycle correctly - your activity may be recreated in various situatons by the OS. 2) for configuration changes you can also have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: @Henry onConfigurationChanged isn't called in this case

Comment: @quangkid : Do you want to keep your text size as it is after change screen size?

Answer (score 1):

**`Redux`** is an inspired predictable state container library for Java/Android. It can help you make your state mutations easier to read and write your application's state.

What is [Redux??](http://redux.js.org/)

Android library project implemented using redux to maintain state of application. [Here](https://github.com/evant/redux)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realize that the simplest way is saving objects in onSaveInstance method an retrieve them back on onCreate